# Prefix to each output of a command on runtime

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, bash-scripting

I am trying to make a modular script. I have several scripts/commands which are called from a single script.
I want to prefix the output of each separate command.

Examle:

My files are **allcommands.sh / command1.sh / command2.sh**

**command1.sh** outputs
`file exists`
`file moved`

**command2.sh** outputs
`file copied`
`file emptied`

**allcommands.sh** runs the scripts **command1.sh** and **command2.sh**

I want to prefix each output of these two scripts like this:
`[command1] file exists`
`[command1] file moved`
`[command2] file copied`
`[command2] file emptied`

Comment: Try running each command piping it through `sed "s/\^/command1 /"`

Comment: Give me please an example with the information that I give. I don't really understand the `sed` functionality. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I assume that what you are doing in your allcommands.sh is:

```
command1.sh
command2.sh
```

Just relace it with

```
command1.sh | sed "s/^/[command1] /"
command2.sh | sed "s/^/[command2] /"
```

Answer (score 10):

A minimal example of `allcommands.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in command{1,2}.sh; do
    ./"$i" | sed 's/^/['"${i%.sh}"'] /'
done
```

With `command1.sh` and `command2.sh` executable and in the same directory just `echo`ing the wanted strings, this gives the shell output:

```
$ ./command1.sh 
file exists
file moved
$ ./command2.sh 
file copied
file emptied
$ ./allcommands.sh 
[command1] file exists
[command1] file moved
[command2] file copied
[command2] file emptied
```

---

#### Quick `sed` breakdown

```
sed 's/^/['"${i%.sh}"'] /'
```

- `s/` enters "regexp pattern match and replace" mode
- `^/` means "match the beginning of every line"
- `${i%.sh}` happens in the shell context and means "`$i`, but strip the suffix `.sh`"
- `['"${i%.sh}"'] /` at first prints a `[`, then exits the quoted context to grab the `$i` variable from the shell, then re-enters to finish with the `]` and a space.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. Your answer was helpful indeed, but @j_kubik's example was just the one I need.

Answer (score 0):

Simple example:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# allcommands.sh

output-prefix() {
  local title="${1/\.[a-zA-Z.0-9-_]*/}"
  title="${title/[.-\/_a-zA-Z0-9]*\//}"
  "$@" \
    2> >(sed "s/^/[$title] [ERR] /" >&2) \
    > >(sed "s/^/[$title] [INF] /")
}

output-prefix ./command1.sh
# [command1] [INF] file exists
# [command1] [INF] file moved

output-prefix ./command2.sh
# [command2] [INF] file copied
# [command2] [INF] file emptied
```

Prefix with a timestamp as a function/script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

output-prefix() {
  local title="$1" ; shift
  "$@" \
    2> >(sed "s/^/$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') [ERR] {$title} /" >&2) \
    > >(sed "s/^/$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') [INF] {$title} /")
}

output-prefix command1 ./command1.sh arg1
# 2023-04-29 17:37:12 [INF] {command1} arg1
# 2023-04-29 17:37:12 [ERR] {command1} test as errout

output-prefix command2 ./command2.sh argB
# 2023-04-29 17:37:12 [INF] {command2} argB
# 2023-04-29 17:37:12 [ERR] {command2} argB as errout
```